# How to use multiple nested IF statements in OpenOffice cell

Tags: if-statement, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

In an OpenOffice/Libre Office spreadsheet, I would like to display a value in a cell **if** two other cells have certain values. After many searches, I didn't find out how to do this. Can someone help solve this please?

In cell G2, I'd like to write a statement saying:

If A2 equals "PayPal Express Checkout Payment Received" **and** if C2 = "GBP", then display the value of F2, else display nothing.

[image: Screenshot of 8 columns of data in OpenOffice spreadsheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(A2="PayPal Express Checkout Payment Received";C2="GBP");F2;"")
```

Answer (score 2):

In Boolean Algebra (used in Basic language programming) the "+" means "OR", and the "*" means "AND".  I find it easier to read this way:

=IF((A2="PayPal Express Checkout Payment Received")*(C2="GBP"),F2,"")

This works quite well in both LibreOffice and other spreadsheet programs.  Please note the sets of parentheses that are required to separate the sections of the statement.

An alternative example shows the possibility of three different values and a null for C2 and nested IF statement to deal with more than two alternatives.  Additional alternatives may be appended to increase the options and length of the statement.  The second 'IF' takes the place of the 'ELSE' in the first condition:

=IF(C2="GPB",F2,IF(C2="GAF",F3,IF(C2="HAP",F4,"")))

Please note that I have used the comma as separator (USA version for formulas).